# Template specialization for classes which have a certain method

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization

I have a templated method of a Lua State class, which tests if the object at a given index is of a given type:

```
template<typename T> bool is(int idx) {
    return luaL_testudata(L, idx, std::remove_pointer<T>::type::name) != NULL;
};
```

and a few specializations:

```
template<> inline bool State::is<bool>(int i){ return lua_isboolean(this->L, i); }
template<> inline bool State::is<int>(int i){ return lua_isinteger(this->L, i); }
//etc...
```

Now I want to add a specialization for any class that has a static "lua_test" method:

```
template<> inline bool State::is<T>(int i){ return T::lua_test(this->L, i); }
```

But I don't know the correct syntax for this. The closest I've come is:

```
template <class T>
inline auto State::is(int idx) ->
decltype(std::declval<T>.lua_test(this, idx), true)
{
    return T::lua_test(this, idx);
}
```

This fails to compile, because apparently the types don't match:

```
templates.hpp:87:13: error: prototype for ‘decltype ((declval<T>.lua_test(((Lua::State*)this), idx), true)) Lua::State::is(int)’ does not match any in class ‘Lua::State’
 inline auto State::is(int idx) ->
             ^~~~~
In file included from [...],
                 from debug.cpp:1:
get.hpp:6:27: error: candidate is: template<class T> bool Lua::State::is(int)
 template<typename T> bool is(int idx) {
```

The idea is supposed to be that the `decltype` statement evaluates to `decltype(true)` (due to the comma operator), ie `bool`, but gcc doesn't seem convinced of this.

This seems like it should be pretty simple, but I've been getting nowhere trying to implement it.

Comment: You have forgotten the function call on std::declval (it should be `decltype(std::declval<T>().lua_test(this, idx), true)`), maybe this is the problem, but I'm not sure. You might have to also add the decltype in the class definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply repeat the return in the `decltype`:

```
struct State
{
    // ....

    template <class T>
    auto is(int idx) -> decltype(T::lua_test(this, idx))
    {
        return T::lua_test(this, idx);
    }
};
```

And for your case, you have to do some work to don't have ambiguous call between the two method.

```
struct low_priority {};
struct high_priority : low_priority {};

struct State
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    bool is(int idx) {
        return is_impl<T>(idx, high_priority{});
    }

private:
    template<typename T>
    bool is_impl(int idx, low_priority) {
        std::cout << "generic\n";
        return luaL_testudata(L, idx, std::remove_pointer<T>::type::name) != NULL;
    }

    template <class T>
    auto is_impl(int idx, high_priority) -> decltype(T::lua_test(this, idx))
    {
        std::cout << "LuaTest\n";
        return T::lua_test(this, idx);
    }

    LuaState L;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93e7a7c1055d2865)

Comment: Will this even compile? This will directly collide with the original syntax `template<typename T> bool is(int idx);` and will result in compilation error for multiple definition of same signature. The OP wants an `is()` method which should be specialized/overloaded for the classes which has `static lua_test()` inside them.

Comment: @iammilind: It compiles, but indeed, it would create an ambiguous call. Demo added to show how to handle all cases.

Comment: Nice. I was not aware of `decltype` based `template` specialization. It will be good if you add another example which invokes normal version. Does this compile with C++11 as per question?

Comment: I think you want to replace `std::remove_point<T>::type::name` with `std::remove_pointer_t<T>{}`. Calling `s.is<char>(42);`  fails to compile otherwise.

Comment: @AndyG: I kept the OP's implementation for the generic case (which indeed doesn't work for `char` but might work for custom type with a `static` `name`).

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand how that works. Hopefully it won't affect runtime performance?

Comment: @Rena: All the dispatching can easily be optimized by compiler and so have no extra cost.

Answer (score 1):

The class method `is()` will be called always with explicit template parameters, such as: `is<some_type>(value)`. Hence in such case you may enclose it as a `static` function into a class for simplicity of `template` specialization.

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct X {   // default
  static bool is (int idx) { return ...; } 
};

template<>
struct X<int, void> {   // `int` specialization
  static bool is (int idx) { return lua_isinteger(...); } 
};

template<>
struct X<bool, void> {   // `bool` specialization
  bool is (int idx) { return lua_isboolean(...); } 
};
```

**Specialization**:

Now we have reserved `typename = void` for ease of SFINAE as following:

```
template<typename T> struct void_ { using type = void; };

template<typename T>  // specialization for those, who contain `lua_test`
struct X<T, typename void_<decltype(&T::lua_test)>::type> { 
  static bool is (int idx) { return T::lua_test(...); } 
};
```

**Usage**:

```
X<some_class>::is(0);
X<int>::is(1);
X<bool>::is(2);
X<some_class_with_lua_test_function>::is(3);
```

It compiles & works in my environment and hence, it should work for you too!

---

**Edit**: I see that you are using `this` inside this method. In such case your method may look like:

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct X {   // default
  static bool is (Lua* const this_, int idx) { return ...; } 
};
// ... other specializations with similar syntax
```